# Random binary list of lists of numbers

Tags: haskell, random

I am trying to get a function that returns a list of lists of zeros or ones, obviously in a random way.

Example:

```
getBinaryRandomList::Int->Int->[[Int]]

Prelude> getBinaryRandomList 4 3
[[1,0,0,1],[1,1,0,1],[0,0,0,1], [0,1,0,1]]
```

So far, i have done this functions:

```
--tuns an `Int` into a `[Int]`. The [Int] would represent a binary number
int2bin :: Int -> [Int]
int2bin 0 = []
int2bin n = mod n 2 : int2bin (div n 2)
```

I have got stuck here, it throws an error at compilation time:

```
--returns a random number
import System.Random
randomInt::(Int,Int)->Int
randomInt x y = do 
                newStdGen
                randomR(x, y) getStdGen
```

Compiling...

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( ag.hs, interpreted )

ag.hs:8:25: parse error on input `randomR'
```

The "main" function would be like this:

```
--n lists number
--d digit number
getBinaryRandomList::Int->Int->[[Int]]
getBinaryRandomList d 0 = []
getBinaryRandomList d n = take d (int2bin(randomInt(0,50))) : getBinaryRandomList(n-1)
```

My approach is the next:

1. Coding a function that creates an aleatory Int number between 0 an n.

> ```
> randomInt::(Int,Int)->Int
> ```

2. Coding a function that converts those aleatory numbers into a list of binaries.

> ```
> int2bin::Int->[Int]  % Already done
> ```

3. Forming a list with those numbers

> ```
>  getBinaryRandomList::Int->Int->[[Int]]
> ```

How could I implement that in Haskell?

Comment: Functions are deterministic and can not give you a random value.  Your `randomInt` operations needs either a seed, generator, or to have `IO`.

Answer (score 1):

As it was pointed out in a comment, you can't create a StdGen without IO, but you can create one in your main function and pass it along in a parameter to your randomInt function, in this way:

```
import System.Random

main = do
    a <- newStdGen
    putStrLn . show . randomInt 0 1 $ a

randomInt:: Int -> Int -> StdGen -> (Int, StdGen)
randomInt x y s = do 
          randomR (x, y) s
```

The error message that you got about RandomR was caused by not importing System.Random.

I hope this helps.

Comment: actually, conceptually speaking: you can get/create a `StdGen` or any other `IO a` value anywhere in pure code — you just can't tell the actual runtime IO system to actually perform it (safely) :)

Comment: Sorry, i made a mistake, i forgot copy the line of code in witch System.Random had been import. I will edit that. Thanks

Comment: Actually, you can create a StdGen without IO - just use `mkStdGen 3`. You just can't create a _random_ StdGen.

Comment: @user5402 indeed. The OP wanted randomness, though.